# How to get Facebook Instant Articles Version of Article (without logging into Facebook?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles

Is there a way to get the Facebook Instant Articles version (HTML) of an article without logging into the FB app and clicking on that article in my feed? It is NOT my website.

Alternatively, is there a way to get the Instant Articles RSS feed for a website?

Comment: _“is there a way to get the Instant Articles RSS feed for a website?”_ – if you know the URL of that feed, and it is publicly accessible …

Comment: It is not publicly accessible. Hmm seems so perverse. Facebook, a closed garden wanting others to adopt an open web standard, but only let them have access to it. Awesome.